# Searching for libraries for improving Android app UI

Tags: android

Maybe it is my impression, but Android apps are less nice than other platforms ... if i use classic ListView and other native objects, the look of an app is not so sexy.... are there UI libraries to use for improving the look of an Android app?

Answer (score 1):

Not really but there is [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid) that can help you getting a more efficient UI.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a WebView and code the UI objects you want to be sexier in HTML/CSS. Hybrid apps are more and more common in these days